# how to select columns from same table with different where clause criteria

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which is similar to the design below:

```
Id   Code     Name    short name     Date1       date2       market
1    12A      AAAA1    a1            2012-03-27  2012-03-27  90
2    13A      AAAA2    a2            2012-03-28  2012-03-28  90
3    14A      AAAA3    a3            NULL        NULL        32
4    15A      AAAA4    a4            NULL        NULL        32
```

I have to build a query such that when I select a code, the codes with market 90, the select should be such a way that the Date1>system date and Date2> Date1 and for other market no criteria is applicable on selection.

I have built the query so far, but I don’t know how to specify the where clause when the market is 90.

```
SELECT A.Id, B.Name [Name], B.Code [Code], Date1 [Date1], Date2 [Date]2, C.Code[Market]
FROM dbo.fn_idlisting(@System_Date) A 
INNER JOIN code B ON A.Id = B.Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Market C ON B.Market_Id = C.Market_Id 
WHERE (Date1 <= @systemDate) AND (Date2 >= Date1)
```

I feel difficult on how to select other codes with market 32 without any where clause.

Comment: Could you please add some more details: knowing something more regarding fn_listing and Market could be useful.  By the way the where clause doesn't specify which are the tables involved ...

Comment: is this for mysql or sql server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL, please ?

Comment: it's pretty clearly sql-server. square brackets and `dbo.` tend to give it away.

Comment: Its Microsoft sql server, and fn_listing will list all the codes for which the the system date is between the date of creation and date of expiry. market contains the market code for market id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this way

```
SELECT A.Id, B.Name [Name], B.Code [Code], Date1 [Date1], Date2 [Date]2, C.Code[Market] 
    FROM dbo.fn_idlisting(@System_Date) A 
    INNER JOIN code B ON A.Id = B.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Market C ON B.Market_Id = C.Market_Id 
    WHERE (Date1 > @System_Date and Date2 >Date1 or c.Code != 90)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statement to include your `Market = 90` logic as follows:

```
SELECT
  A.Id,
  B.Name [Name],
  B.Code [Code],
  Date1 [Date1],
  Date2 [Date2],
  C.Code [Market]
FROM
  dbo.fn_idlisting(@System_Date) A
  INNER JOIN code B
    ON A.Id = B.Id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Market C
    ON B.Market_Id = C.Market_Id
WHERE
  Date1 <= CASE WHEN C.Code = 90 THEN @systemDate ELSE Date1 END 
  AND 
  Date2 >= CASE WHEN C.Code = 90 THEN Date1 ELSE Date2 END
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have understand from your question is your table name is fn_idlisting and you have only one table. Try below.

Note: I have not used equal to as you only mention > and < for date1 and date2, you can use it if wants to change your date range criteria.

> ```
> select * from fn_idlisting 
> where market=90 and date1>cast(SYSDATETIME() as DATE)
> and date2>date1
> union
> select * from fn_idlisting 
> where market<>90
> ```